# How to store 2 GameObjects from InputField in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, path-finding, input-field

I'm  trying to make a mobile app that shows the user path on Canvas Image from one waypoint to another.  I'm using Dijkstra algorithm from here https://github.com/hasanbayatme/unity-dijkstras-pathfinding

The user  should input start node, then input destination node. The program should be able to read these two inputs and store them into the Graph.GetShortestPath(start, end); then draw the line from the nodes, stored in path array. I used code from here  to read inputs
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1520095/how-can-i-find-objects-with-using-inputfield.html

seems like it reads them and finds the node i need, but I'm stuck in storing the 2nd input and showing path.

Here is the code i tried:

```
{
    public InputField inputField;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    protected Node m_From;
    protected Node m_To;
    protected FindPath m_Path = new FindPath();
    List<GameObject> targets = new List<GameObject>();
   [SerializeField]
    protected Graph m_Graph;

/// <summary>
    /// Indicates an object has been found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    public void TurnOn(GameObject target)
    {
        targets.Add(target);
        GameObject lineObject = new GameObject();
        lineRenderer = lineObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;

        // Customize the input field according to the gameObject
        // Do whathever you want
        if (m_From == null)
        {
            m_From = targets[0];
        }
        else
        {
            m_To = targets[1];
        }

        m_Path = m_Graph.GetShortestPath(m_From, m_To);

        Vector3[] checkPointArray = new Vector3[m_Path.nodes.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Path.nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 checkpointpos = m_Path.nodes[i].transform.position;
            checkPointArray[i] = new Vector3(checkpointpos.x, checkpointpos.y);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, checkPointArray[i]);
        }
        

            targets.Clear();}
     
        
        inputField.textComponent.color = Color.black;
    }
```

Thank you for your help in advance!